# Java/Android - Most efficient way to store many variables

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, variables

I'm creating an app and I need to store hundreds of strings that can be called or used in if/else functions. I was thinking about using SQLite to try and hold a load of them but I'm not very experience with it and I'm not too sure how I can manually store strings in it. Is there a simpler way to store many different strings besides using a large array or a database?

Comment: Databases and file systems are meant for large data storage. If you store large data in memory, it would cause performance hit. Since the data is large, you can get a chunk of it and save it in the memory using array or JSON or map whatever based on your code flow and keep updating it as per some rules like LRU etc... This is just a suggestion from my side. Not a concrete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I'll probably have to use a database but I'm asking mainly if there is other means of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask yourself how you're going to use these strings. Will you load them all once into memory when the app starts up or will you constantly be pulling bits and pieces throughout the application's life-cycle? If your answer is the latter than a viable option in Android would be to use `SharedPreferences` which uses a key/value pair format to store data on the device. If your answer is the former then a database (SQLite) would probably be better.

[See Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for more information on SharedPreferences.

Comment: This is interesting I've never heard of SharedPreferences before. My situation is the later and I need to pull random strings throughout the use of the app not all at once.

Comment: @EoinCoogan Then I'd definitely suggest taking a look at it. I'm not sure how the strings you need are related but you can either store them individually with `putString(String key, String value)` or if you have related groups of strings that you want to store together you can use `putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.